# Double WHERE IN OR in MySQL query does AND instead of OR

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, where-in

I have the following MySQL query as a result of a piece of laravel code. And I'm trying to figure out where the code fails by analysing the resulting query.

The query should select all the twitter_statuses where there is a tag_id in `twitter_status_tags` *OR* `twitter_user_tags`, but currently it returns all the twitter_statuses where there is a tag_id in `twitter_status_tags` *AND* `twitter_user_tags`.

As far as I can tell, the query below is for the OR, but aparently MySQL thinks otherwise.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `project_twitter_statuses` 
       INNER JOIN `twitter_statuses` 
               ON `twitter_statuses`.`id` = 
                  `project_twitter_statuses`.`twitter_status_id` 
       INNER JOIN `twitter_user_tags` 
               ON `twitter_user_tags`.`twitter_user_id` = 
                  `twitter_statuses`.`twitter_user_id` 
       INNER JOIN `twitter_status_tags` 
               ON `twitter_status_tags`.`twitter_status_id` = 
                  `twitter_statuses`.`id` 
WHERE  `project_twitter_statuses`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
       AND ( `twitter_user_tags`.`tag_id` IN ( '3', '6', '8', '12' ) 
              OR `twitter_status_tags`.`tag_id` IN ( '3', '6', '8', '12' ) ) 
GROUP  BY `twitter_statuses`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `twitter_statuses`.`datetime` ASC;
```

For those who are interested, this is the code in my laravel app

```
$projectTwitterStatuses = ProjectTwitterStatus::join('twitter_statuses','twitter_statuses.id','=','project_twitter_statuses.twitter_status_id');

// Tags
if(!empty($tagsSelectedArray)) {
    $projectTwitterStatuses = $projectTwitterStatuses
        ->join('twitter_user_tags','twitter_user_tags.twitter_user_id','=','twitter_statuses.twitter_user_id')
        ->join('twitter_status_tags','twitter_status_tags.twitter_status_id','=','twitter_statuses.id')
        ->where(function($query) use ($tagsSelectedArray)
        {
            $query->orWhereIn('twitter_user_tags.tag_id',$tagsSelectedArray)
                  ->orWhereIn('twitter_status_tags.tag_id',$tagsSelectedArray);
        })
        ->groupBy('twitter_statuses.id');
}

$projectTwitterStatuses = $projectTwitterStatuses->orderBy('twitter_statuses.datetime')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Can you tell how your tables are related to each other, it could be done using Eloquent ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I managed to get it to work using the model relations. However, that solutions slows the retrieval of data down extensively. So I reverted back to using the tables in some cases. I am curently trying to get it done using `where has`

Answer (score 0):

Inner join on both tag tables is giving you the effect of an and, you want outer joins to get none, both or either

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `project_twitter_statuses` 
INNER JOIN  `twitter_statuses` ON  `twitter_statuses`.`id` =  `project_twitter_statuses`.`twitter_status_id` 
Left JOIN  `twitter_user_tags` ON  `twitter_user_tags`.`twitter_user_id` =  `twitter_statuses`.`twitter_user_id` 
Left JOIN  `twitter_status_tags` ON  `twitter_status_tags`.`twitter_status_id` =  `twitter_statuses`.`id` 
WHERE  `project_twitter_statuses`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND (
`twitter_user_tags`.`tag_id` 
IN (
'3',  '6',  '8',  '12'
)
OR  `twitter_status_tags`.`tag_id` 
IN (
'3',  '6',  '8',  '12'
)
)
GROUP BY  `twitter_statuses`.`id` 
ORDER BY  `twitter_statuses`.`datetime` ASC;
```

Adding this

```
Where (`twitter_user_tags`.`twitter_user_id` is not null) Or
      (`twitter_status_tags`.`twitter_status_id` is not null)
```

would chop out records where neither tag exists.

Comment: sorry for the delay in my response. I am currently trying to get it to work with turning the query over. Not starting with the project but with the twitter status and using a `where has` structure check if the are linked to the project.

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is filtering to records where either of the following is true:

- project_twitter_statuses`.`deleted_at IS NULL  AND `twitter_user_tags`.`tag_id` IN ( '3', '6', '8', '12' )
- project_twitter_statuses`.`deleted_at IS NULL  AND `twitter_status_tags`.`tag_id` IN ( '3', '6', '8', '12' )

What's also filtering records in this query are your 3 inner joins. Inner joins only return matching records between tables, you'll want to use `OUTER` joins to avoid excess filtering.

Also, table aliases are very helpful for making code easier to read.